# Design cell make UITableView slow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Here is my problematique: I design my cell in my UItableView, so I added a title, a little description and an image.
All thoses element are store in my database, so in my UIViewController I calculate every position to have a nice cell, if there is no image in a cell I change the position of the title and the little description.

To check if the image is present or not I do something like that:

```
if ([fiche linkImg]!=@"") { //draw position of element }
or
if ([fiche.linkImg length] > 0 ) { //draw position of element }
```

My problem is when I begin to slide in my tableview its very slow and often very often crash, and the error are sometimes:

[CALayerArray listImg]
or
[NSCFArray listImg]:

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is a tiny bit confusing to see what is the problem.

I would suggest having a look at how to accomplish adding custom stuff to cell.

Have a read of [apple's doc on UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/Introduction/Introduction.html) especially [a closer look at Table-View cells](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1), if you scroll down in that section you will find examples of exactly the type of cells you are trying to create (text with pictures).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding like this

if([fiche linkImg]!=nil)

I tried and succeeded